# Show that if a partial order has all least upper bounds, then it necessarily also has all greatest lower bounds and vice versa.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, upper-lower-bounds

any hints or solutions for question?

Show that if a partial order has all least upper bounds,
then it necessarily also has all greatest lower bounds and
vice versa.

Comment: You can get the greatest lower bound of a set $A$ by taking the least upper bound of the set $B$ of all lower bounds of $A$.